# How to Rotate Accordion Arrow 180 Degrees on Click?

Tags: javascript, animation, accordion

I want to be able to click on the accordion question and have the arrow rotate 180 degrees up and then back down if I again click on the question.

I already figured out how to expand the accordion answer on click using javascript so I just have the arrow left.

Can anyone assist?

Here is the html, css, and js code.

`

```
<div class="faqs-container">


        
        <div class="faqs-question">


            <button>
                <h3>Which services do you provide?</h3>
                <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i> 

            </button>

            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. </p>


            
        </div>

</div>
```

`

`

```
.faqs-container {

    max-width: 60%;
    margin: 0 auto;

}



.faqs-question {
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #999;
    margin-bottom: 30px;

}


.faqs-question button{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 20px 15px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: 'interstate', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #300600;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.faqs-question button h3{
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: 'interstate', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
}


.faqs-question i{
    font-size: 48px;

}


.faqs-question p {
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: 'Merriweather-Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 55px;
    color: #444;
    max-height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 0.6s ease;
}


.faqs-question p.show{
    max-height: 30vh;
    opacity: 1;
    padding: 10px 0px 40px 15px;
    margin-bottom: 35px;
}
```

`

`

```
<script>
    
 const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');

buttons.forEach( button =>{
    button.addEventListener('click',()=>{

          const faq = button.nextElementSibling;
            faq.classList.toggle('show');
            
    })
} )


</script>
```

`

I don't know where to start with the javascript. I'm still fairly new with all of this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to toggle a class on the icon as well:

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');

buttons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const faq = button.nextElementSibling;
    faq.classList.toggle('show');
    button.querySelector('i').classList.toggle('rotate')
  })
})
```

```css
.faqs-container {
  max-width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.faqs-question {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #999;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.faqs-question button {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px 15px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: 'interstate', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #300600;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.faqs-question button h3 {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: 'interstate', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.faqs-question i {
  transition: 0.2s;
  font-size: 48px;
}

.faqs-question p {
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: 'Merriweather-Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 55px;
  color: #444;
  max-height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
}

.faqs-question p.show {
  max-height: 30vh;
  opacity: 1;
  padding: 10px 0px 40px 15px;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
}

.rotate {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-xh6O/CkQoPOWDdYTDqeRdPCVd1SpvCA9XXcUnZS2FmJNp1coAFzvtCN9BmamE+4aHK8yyUHUSCcJHgXloTyT2A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<div class="faqs-container">
  <div class="faqs-question">
    <button>
                <h3>Which services do you provide?</h3>
                <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i> 
            </button>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was tearing my hair out and you made it so clear and simple! This is my first question on stackoverflow btw  :)